# Deletion with API sometimes works and sometimes it does not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I am trying to delete files from folder with API call.
It seems to work randomly, some files get deleted, some don't.

The data structure is as follow:

Each folder object has files property.

In `files_to_delete` I have files to delete and index of folder in folders array.
In API call I put whole folder object
I remove file with lodash remove function.

Any idea why it does not work?

```
angular.forEach(files_to_delete, function(file_to_delete) {
  _.remove(folders[file_to_delete.index].files, function(file) {
   if (file === file_to_delete) {
         $http.put('/save_folders_file', folders[file_to_delete.index])       
     return (file === file_to_delete)
             });
```

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without a [mcve].

Comment: `return (file === file_to_delete);` in an `if` block where the condition is `(file === file_to_delete)` seems odd. Surely it should be `return true;`...?

Answer (score 2):

Your example isn't entirely clear, but it looks like you save the container the files are in **repeatedly**, each time you find a file to delete. That seems chaotic. It also assumes that Lodash modifies the container *as* it's doing the loop, but the documentation doesn't say it does, and a simple (perhaps naive) test suggests it doesn't:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var evens = _.remove(array, function(n) {
  console.log(n, JSON.stringify(array));
  return n % 2 == 0;
});
console.log("array", JSON.stringify(array));
console.log("evens", JSON.stringify(evens));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

When I run that, I see:

```
1 [1,2,3,4]
2 [1,2,3,4]
3 [1,2,3,4]
4 [1,2,3,4]
array [1,3]
evens [2,4]
```

...which suggests that it does the callbacks first, then goes back and removes the relevant entries.

Even if it did remove them as it went, though, those overlapping HTTP requests would bother me a lot.

Instead, I'd save the container **once**, when done, after all the files are removed:

```
angular.forEach(files_to_delete, function(file_to_delete) {
  const removed = _.remove(folders[file_to_delete.index].files, function(file) {
    return file === file_to_delete;
  });
  if (removed.length) {
    $http.put('/save_folders_file', folders[file_to_delete.index])       
  }
});
```